# Table not found

Tags: java, mysql, h2

```
public void tableupdate(JTable jTable1, String fill) {

    try {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:file:D:/Inventory.db", "sa", "");

            Statement stat = con.createStatement();
            fill = "SELECT * FROM BOOKDESC";
            ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(fill);

            while (jTable1.getRowCount() > 0) {
                ((DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel()).removeRow(0);

            }
            int columns = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Object[] row = new Object[columns];
                for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                    row[i - 1] = rs.getObject(i);

                }
                ((DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel()).insertRow(rs.getRow() - 1, row);

            }
            rs.close();
            stat.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }

}
```

So basically, whenever I run this I get this error.

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "BOOKDESC" not found;SQL statement: SELECT * FROM BOOKDESC [42102-154]
```

I have tried adding

```
;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1

;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false
```

To the connection URL, but it doesn't work

Comment: no question is stupid, and yes the table exists as i have added data to it

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include a piece of code that connects to the db and successfully inserts into that table? Because other than opening the wrong file or trying to query a non-existing table I don't see how that query could fail.

Comment: So replacing the present query with an INSERT works?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/6254777bdf5965fd9600df3eaf4e5f7a have a look

Comment: the connection code is there?

Comment: Did you commit after inserting the records into the table. If you don't commit, it might show in sql editor but will fail if you run from code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error code `[42102-154]` means that it was thrown from H2 1.3.154. This archaic version of H2 can't read the database that was created by 1.4.200 (from your screenshot of H2 Console) and creates a new empty database in another format with different file name extension.

You need to update the H2's jar in the classpath of your application to the version 1.4.200.